# Create files in a loop with multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocess

I am trying to write a python script that parses big xml files and converts them to csv files, I tried to get a loop that allows to create as much csv files as the number of CPUs assigned, in other words each CPU will create a csv file of its own.
Here's the script :

```
repartition = defaultdict(list)
for i, in_filename in enumerate(FichList): #reading xml files in the directory
    m = i % num_process #num_process is a configuration variable
    repartition[m].append(in_filename)

for i in range(1,num_process): 
    lock_filename = TargetCsvFilenamePath + os.sep + "HNI_mxmltocsv_R50_multiprocess_"+ num_process_display +"_"+ time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S',time.localtime())+".csv.lock"
    fichier = codecs.open(TargetCsvFilenamePath + os.sep + "HNI_mxmltocsv_R50_multiprocess_"+ num_process_display +"_"+ time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S',time.localtime())+".csv", "w",encoding='utf-8')
    fichier.write("ID_FLUX;LIB_FLUX;ID_EMETTEUR;ID_PRM;FILE_NAME;ID_DEST;DATE_CREA_FICH;ID_CONT;ID_ABO;PAS_PUBLI;UNIT_MSR_PDC;Date_Releve;Id_Affaire;Horodate;VAL_MSR_PDC;INDC_VRAIS_PDC\n")
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=SplitFichierR50, args=(repartition[i], fichier, lock_filename,))
    p.start()
    liste_process.append(p)
    fichier.close()
    os.unlink(lock_filename)
```

I am using python 2.7 and to execute this script we need to import other libraries such as : threading, multiprocessing, codecs, collections, filelock, os, sys and csv. And "SplitfichierR50(in_filename_list,out_file, lock_file):" is just a parsing function.
I'am just a beginner in python, any help would be apreciated !!

Comment: What goes wrong then? Could you please edit your question with more information about what should happen and what actually happens? You might want to include your SplitFichierR50 function as well.

Comment: The function is included "p = multiprocessing.Process(target=SplitFichierR50, args=(repartition[i], fichier, lock_filename,))", but when executing the script it returns only one csv file, and what is expected is generate a csv file for each used CPU (num_process variable)

Comment: My problem is with the file creating not the writing, actually the writing code works well